# JNI NewDoubleArray Memory Leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I have Java application which use C library with JNI.

I send to the JNI a String and want him to return jdoubleArray.

```
JNIEXPORT jdoubleArray JNICALL Java_com_1funcA (JNIEnv *env, jclass class, jstring text){

const char *a = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, text, 0);
char *b;
funcB(a, &b);

c_array c;
c.data = b;
c.count = strlen(b);

d_array d = funcA(c);

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, text, a);
jdoubleArray java_buffer = (*env)->NewDoubleArray(env, d.count);
(*env)->SetDoubleArrayRegion(env, java_buffer, 0, d.count, d.doubleArr);

free(d.doubleArr);
free(b);

return java_buffer;}
```

it works as supposed to but there is a memory leak from those lines.

```
jdoubleArray java_buffer = (*env)->NewDoubleArray(env, d.count);
```

the java_buffer is returned to the java so i cant release it here.
and it seems that the GC dont release him.

I have followed [this](http://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/doc/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/array.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) but i don't find the right way to stop the memory leak.

I tried to change it to global reference,
also tried to do this inside a thread and try to detach it but still receive the sames results.

Comment: How did you conclude that there's a memory leak (and that it isn't a false positive)?

Comment: I run the java application in while(true), and the memory usage is getting full, and eventually after 1~ hour it crashed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a leak. `NewDoubleArray` creates a local reference. As https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#local_references states "Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call." the local reference is deleted when the native method returns. The Java side creates a new reference for it, so it won't get garbage collected too soon. Once Java also doesn't reference the object anymore it will become eligible for garbage collection.

Be aware that if you create a global reference and never delete that again you will indeed create a leak.

Comment: as i said, if i call the function in a while(true) the memory usage is getting full.

Comment: Then the leak must be elsewhere. You might be holding on to references on the Java side or have missed a `free`. Check where exactly the crash occurs. To catch a possible `OutOfMemoryError` in the native code check the return values of the JNI calls before using them and use `ExceptionOccurred` (and maybe `ExceptionDescribe`)